# Intent for Phone ringtone picker android

Tags: android, android-sdcard, ringtone

I am developing an android app, where I want to display the user a list of phone INBUILT ringtones only. Below is the code I have tried.

```
 private void pickRingTone() 
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, "Choose Ringtone");
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, ringtoneUri);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_DEFAULT_URI, ringtoneUri);

    this.startActivityForResult(intent, 5);
}
```

The above code works fine, But It also displays the ringtones fetching from memory card(SD card)  as well ,along with INBUILT ringtones. I want to display on the INBUILT ringtones of the phone. How can I achieve this. Please Help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I run this code, i can only select internal ringtones. What android version do you have?

Comment: I have tested in 2.3.5 V .. Galaxy S.. i am getting a list on Inbuilt ringtone, along with the ringtones picked from SD card.

Comment: show me more info about ringtoneUri